# Count Nice Pairs in Leetcode gives me wrong result

Tags: java, algorithm

I recently encountered an interesting question in Leetcode. Here is the question [URL](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-nice-pairs-in-an-array/).

So, in simple words, count the number of pairs that match the following condition for 2 indices `i` and `j`.

```
nums[i] + rev(nums[j]) == nums[j] + rev(nums[i])
```

The trivial solution I thought was maintaining the count of an integer and its reverse and finding NC2.

Here is my approach,

```
class Solution {
    public int countNicePairs(int[] nums) {
        
        int[] rev = new int[nums.length];
        
        for(int i=0;i< nums.length;i++){
            rev[i] = Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(nums[i])).reverse().toString());
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rev));
        
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            int diff = Math.abs(rev[i]-nums[i]);
            map.put(diff,map.getOrDefault(diff,0)+1);
        }
        
        int mod = (int)(1e9 +7);
        
        long op = 0;
        
        for(int val: map.values()){
            op +=((long)(val)*(long)(val-1)/(long)2);
            op = op%mod;
        }
        
        
        return (int)(op%mod);
    }
}
```

This code fails for 4 test cases. And the example one mentioned there is pasted in https://justpaste.it/2n1ka

```
My answer : 92976930
Expected answer : 92974217
```

As you can see the input is huge and I am not able to debug what is the problem with my code.

Comment: I get **Wrong Answer** with your code for the following input: `[42,97,24]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
int diff = Math.abs(rev[i]-nums[i]);
```

You assume that sign of the integer in the difference doesn't matter but *it does*. For example:

`[21,12]`

Here, both numbers have their reverse as an element of the array itself and they aren't a nice pair as `(21 - 12) != (12 - 21)`. Note that sign matters here and the answer to this is `0` but yours returns `1` which is incorrect.

**Solution:**

Just remove the absolute value check. Your calculation should follow the `nums[i] - rev(nums[i]) = nums[j] - rev(nums[j])` but you are doing the other way round, like multiplying both sides by `-1`(which is also ok). So, just do

```
int diff = rev[i]-nums[i];
```

---

**Side note:** You can remove the `rev` array completely by just calculating `rev` during the for loop iteration itself for each element.